# Modify existing setup for Office Add-In

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, ms-office

I have created a couple of COM-Addins for MS Excel and MS Visio using Visual Studio 2013. Everything runs perfectly as planned.

As it is a living project, I have to update the code when we change some stuff. So I have to create new setup files and redistribute them to my team members to install it on their machine. The problem is, every time they have to uninstall the previous version before installing the new version that I have provided. 
Is there a way that when we run the setup file, it ask to whether to "repair" or "modify" the existing installation so that we do not have to uninstall the previous version every time?

I used the "Install Shield" in Visual Studio to create the setup file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make every build be able to perform a major upgrade (uninstall old + install new) over an installed build. You'd add an entry in the Upgrade table to make this happen - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372379(v=vs.85).aspx

The Upgrade table entry could look like:

```
UpgradeCode        MinVersion MaxVersion Language Attributes Remove ActionProperty
<Your UpgradeCode> Null       Null       Null     1          Null   OLD_PRODUCT_FOUND
```